# Does "this" keyword changes msg.sender on inherited methods invocations?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

Take this scenario:

```
Contract A {
   function whoIsSender() public returns (address){
      return (msg.sender);
   }
}

Contract B is A {
   function withThis() public returns (address){
      return (this.whoIsSender());
   }

   function withoutThis() public returns (address){
      return (whoIsSender());
   }
}
```

I was expecting both functions to return the same. Apparently it is not. It seems that using the `this` keyword breaks it to a contract-to-contract invocation and then `msg.sender` becomes the contract address instead of the wallet? Is this by design and can someone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is touched on a bit here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters, but essentially what you're saying is correct.

`<address>.<function>()` (e.g. `this.whoIsSender()`) sends a message to the contract at that address. This is an external call, and `msg.sender` is the address of the account that made the call.

`<function>()` (e.g. `whoIsSender()`) does an internal function call (just a JUMP).

Comment: How about checking own balance using `this.balance`? Is it an external call? Is there any other way to get contract's own balance other than `this.balance`?

Comment: No, `this.balance` is not any sort of call. That syntax is also deprecated: use `address(this).balance` instead.